# Modificar propiedad de un objeto

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo este objeto array de objetos, y que los guarde en el localstorage para poder hacer un "falso login"

```
var usuarios = [
    { userName: 'kevin44', pass: '44', email: 'aaa@gmail', deposito: 5000 },
    { userName: 'kevin33', pass: '33', email: 'bbb@gmail', deposito: 0 },
    { userName: 'kevin22', pass: '22', email: 'ccc@gmail', deposito: 1000 },
    { userName: 'kevin11', pass: '11', email: 'ddd@gmail', deposito: 3000 },
];
```

Yo ya tengo todo hecho para tener uno de esos usuarios guardados en una variable y ahora quiero modificarle la propiedad deposito, como hagoo para modificarle la propiedad y que en el localstorage se sobreescriba?

Comment: Lo que está incluido en la pregunta es la declaración de una Array de objetos no un JSON.

Comment: Agrega un [mvce] así como un breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: Hola Kevin, ¿cómo estás leyendo los datos desde el localStorage para validar el usuario?

Comment: `var persona;

persona = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario'));`

Answer (score 2):

Lo que está incluido en la pregunta es una Array de objetos. Para modificar la propiedad depósito de un objeto en particular, digamos el primero, puedes usar algo como lo siguiente:

```
usuarios[0].deposito = 100;
```

Para modificar todos los objetos, ya dependerá del tipo de modificación que quieras hacer. Por ejemplo, si todos los valores de depósito van a ser cero

```
usuarios.forEach((o) => o.deposito = 0);
```

```js
var usuarios = [
    { userName: 'kevin44', pass: '44', email: 'aaa@gmail', deposito: 5000 },
    { userName: 'kevin33', pass: '33', email: 'bbb@gmail', deposito: 0 },
    { userName: 'kevin22', pass: '22', email: 'ccc@gmail', deposito: 1000 },
    { userName: 'kevin11', pass: '11', email: 'ddd@gmail', deposito: 3000 },
];

usuarios.forEach((o) => o.deposito = 0);

console.log(usuarios);
```

Comment: Bien, yyo estoy haciendo una "billetera virtual" tengo un login donde me conecto con uno de estos "usuarios" y ya tengo todo en variables, el problema es cuando deposito o retiro dinero no se como sumarle o restarle a la propiedad deposito del objeto json los valores correspondiente!

Comment: @KevinCánepa Edita tu pregunta para añadir a ella todos los detalles relevantes.

Comment: Si perdon me di cuenta que me comi varios detalles importantes